# python-mode python interpreter & cjrh/vim-conda

Tags: vimscript-python, plugin-spf13

I'm having a bit of trouble with running scripts with python-mode while in a specific conda virtual environment.

I've installed spf13 & an additional plugin ([`vim-conda`](https://github.com/cjrh/vim-conda)) which allows to change conda virtual environment inside vim. vim-conda works exactly as it's supposed to:

```
:CondaChangeEnv py35
:!python %
```

executes my Python script in shell with libraries specific to py35 environment

But if i use `:PymodeRun` (from [`python-mode`](https://github.com/klen/python-mode)) to run the same script it throws an error which says that it's unable to find libraries I mentioned above.

Running `:echo system("python -V")` show proper version of Python (different for different conda environments)

Any help on how to explore this will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `:PymodeRun`? That's not a standard command or part of the vim-conda plugin as far as I can see. Judging from the error, it sounds like that is trying to run `:python` and not `:!python`?

Comment: Thank you for the edits :) Looks much nicer now. `:PymodeRun` is a command that python-mode.vim uses to execute python scripts. Does `:python` depends on the current enviroment? If not, then I probably should search for another way to run python scripts from vim: run `:!python %` in a tmux split or somehing...

Comment: A quick look at the python-mode plugin indeed reveals that this uses `:python`. When you use `:python` Vim uses `libpython` and not the `/bin/python` binary. I think that in recent versions Vim introduced some settings to control *which* library it uses but I haven't had time to investigate how this works yet (see [`:help 'pythondll'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27pythondll%27)). Also note that in Neovim the Python script support was revamped, and I believe that *DOES* use the `/bin/python` binary.